# Javascript - this is undefined

Tags: javascript, prototype, this, addeventlistener

I'm building a support chat box plugin follow [this article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-your-own-javascript-modal-plugin)

My problem is when I click submit button, console shows error "that.connectServer is not a function" and after that, when send message, sendMsg funtion is undefined.

I spent a lot of time to find the solution but I can't. How can I fix is?

My support chat box: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b393hwu2/5/)

```
function eventListener() {
    var that = this;

    this.submitName.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (that.inputName.value.trim() !== "") {
            writeCookie("client-name", that.inputName.value);
            that.body.removeChild(that.inputName);
            that.body.removeChild(that.submitName);
            that.body.querySelector("p:not(.greeting)").innerHTML = "Success. Please input your message.";
            that.connectServer().bind(that);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `connectServer` is not defined anywhere in your code.  How do you expect to call it?

Comment: what is `connectServer` and and why are you passing `this` to `that`? what's the point? also what is `this` supposed to be?

Comment: @ted `that` is a reference to the `this` that exists when the function is created so that it cannot be changed by a subsequent rebind.

Comment: Please see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting code elsewhere is not optimal, links rot. The code posted here is different to the code posted there.

Comment: The error message "*that.connectServer is not a function*" is telling you that *that* **is** defined, but that its *connectServer* property is not a function (i.e. it's not callable). If the value of *that* was undefined you'd get a different error (e.g. TypeError: undefined is not an object).

Comment: @Tibrogargan - I love the guessing game but he/she could have specified what `this` is and leave the mystery out of the equation... I was merely trying to ask what element is this function bound to...